# установить программу на удалённой windows машине

Tags: c++, windows, active-directory, msi

Добрый день!
Не могу сообразить как загуглить даже)
Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении копать?
Хочу в доменной сети (может это и не важно) автоматически разворачивать программу.
Понимаю, что вроде как msi пакеты для этого используются. А что дальше (или раньше)? Как программно запустить процесс установки ПО (службы) на удалённой машине?
Буду признателен за ссылки по теме.
Спасибо!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816102/how-to-use-group-policy-to-remotely-install-software-in-windows-server

Comment: 1. Есть DameWare. Она позволяют делать удаленную установку, но она предназначена для enterprise и цена у неё соответствующая. 
2. Можно попробовать бесплатную PsExec: https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Comment: Если ты админ в своей сетке, можно пробросить SSH и написать простенький bat-ник.

Comment: В AD (в доменной сети) для администратора есть масса способов поставить на машину домена что угодно, используя GPO(групповые политики)